Mobile VAPT internet issue using Burpsuite/ZAP
I was exploring to use Burpsuite and ZAP for VAPT mobile testing. As instructed over the internet, I underwent the following steps.

Used Android studio's virtual device manager with Pixel 9 API 35 as an emulator.
Generated a certificate in Burpsuite/ZAP in the extension .cer/.crt
Installed the certificate into the mobile as a CA certificate.
Gave the proxy connection IP address of the Burpsuite/ZAP into the phone where both are under the same wifi connection.

After applying these steps, I see the traffic only through Google Chrome, but not through any other apps on the phone as it says no internet connection for those apps excluding google chrome. So what can be done ???
